# Swift: just 1 fractional digits for NSLengthFormatter

Tags: swift, digits, nsnumberformatter

I use the NSLengthFormatter to show the right entity like meters, feets, yards etc.
The method works, but I don't get the right quantity of fractional digits.

```
let distance = getDistanceAsDouble() //636.62084358567 in meters
        let format = String(format: "%.1f",distance) //636.6

        if let formattedDouble = Double(format) {
            let lengthFormatter = NSLengthFormatter()
            let formattedDistance = lengthFormatter.stringFromMeters(formattedDouble) 
            lbl.text = "\(formattedDistance)" // printed: 697.936 yd
        }
```

I googled, but I can't find how configure the NSLengthFormatter. 
The NSNumberFormatter has properties like `numberStyle` or `maximumFractionDigitis`, but NSLengthFormatter hasn't... or?

I tried to cast `formattedDistance` to Double that I can use `String(format: ""...` again. This doesn't work because `formattedDistance` contains "yd" (or another entity).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `NSLengthFormatter` has a property `numberFormatter`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSLengthFormatter` has a property `numberFormatter: NSNumberFormatter`, so use that to set it, like so...

```
if let formattedDouble = Double(format) {
    let lengthFormatter = NSLengthFormatter()
    lengthFormatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1 // *****
    let formattedDistance = lengthFormatter.stringFromMeters(formattedDouble)
    print("\(formattedDistance)") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.4.2

```
if let formattedDouble = Double(format) {
   let lengthFormatter = LengthFormatter()
   lengthFormatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1 // *****
   let formattedDistance = lengthFormatter.string(fromMeters: formattedDouble)
}
```